# Prove Holder inequality by using $a^{\theta}b^{1-\theta}\leq\theta a+(1-\theta)b$ for all $a,b\geq0$ and $\theta\in[0,1]\\$

Tags: holder-inequality

Known that $a^{\theta}b^{1-\theta}\leq\theta a+(1-\theta)b$ for all $a,b\geq0$ and $\theta\in[0,1]\\$.
Now I want to prove, for $x,y\in R^n$ and $p,q>1$ s.t. $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_iy_i} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|y_i|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}$.
Here is the hint: $let\quad a = \frac{|x_i|^p}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^p}\quad b = \frac{|y_i|^q}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|y_j|^q}$ and $\theta=\frac{1}{p}.$
$\quad$ I've tried to plug in the formula as hint indicated and moved the RHS of the desired inequality to one side but don't know what to do next.

Comment: Are you sure that it is done by AM-GM Inequality? I know that you are going to prove Holder's Inequality

Comment: I think it can be proved by AM-GM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume first that $\sum |x_i|^{p}=\sum |y_i|^{q}=1$. Then we get $|x_i|^{p\theta}|y_i|^{q(1-\theta)}=|x_iy_i| $. Hence $\sum |x_iy_i| \leq \sum _i(\frac  1 p  |x_i|^{p} +\frac  1 q |y_i|^{q}) \leq 1$. This proves the result when $\sum |x_i|^{p}=\sum |y_i|^{q}=1$. For the general case just apply what you have proved  with $x_i$ replaced by  $\frac {x_i} {(\sum |x_i|^{p})^{1/p}}$ and $y_i$ replaced by  $\frac {y_i} {(\sum |q_i|^{p})^{1/q}}$.

Proof without going to the special case:

Let $A=(\sum |x_i|^{p})^{1/p}$ and  $A=(\sum |x_i|^{p})^{1/p}$. Then $\frac 1 A|x_i| \frac 1 B|y_i| \leq \frac 1 p |x_i|^{p}/A^{p}+\frac 1 q |y_i|^{q}/A^{q}$. Summing this and multiplying by $AB$ we get $\sum |x_iy_i| \leq \frac  1 p(\sum |x_i|^{p} /A^{p-1}+\frac  1 q(\sum |y_i|^{q} /B^{q-1}$. Now can you finish the proof?

Comment: You can do  this in single step, but  have considered  a special case first because it is easier to type the proof in this case.

Comment: I've tried but it seems not working. Would you please explain in more details?

Comment: @Walls Can you  tell which step in my answer you have difficulty with?

Comment: When replacing the $x_i$, I've got concerns when generalizing the special case. Does your solution follow the hint? I've tried what the hint says and I've moved the RHS of the goal to one side but the other side seems to be too complicated and I cannot see how it relates to $\sum{x_i y_i}$

Comment: @Walls I have given a direct proof. You should get $\frac 1 p AB+\frac 1 q AB=AB$ at the end of the proof.